# I get the error "Reload already in progress, ignoring request"

Tags: flutter, async-await, flutter-web

After receiving this error, the screen stops working ("Syncing files to Device Edge ...")

What could be the reason of this problem?
[See code here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqQgQ.png)

I can't understand why it's happening. After this error my widget renders before async function fun.

Comment: `reload already in progress, ingoring request` ussualy pop up when you did `ctrl+s` twice so when you doing the hot restart and it not finish. and you click another `ctrl+s` so it didn't do another hot restart

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ("Syncing files to Device Edge ...") is a async function, program waits for it to finish. But since you try to hotreload before, it can not respond. It is better to just stop the program and re-run again. Or refresh instead of hotreload